# Unstable manifold of height function on torus

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, morse-theory

I am currently reading Morse Theory. From the following picture I have to calculate the unstable manifolds of different critical points. Here our Morse function $f:T^2\to \Bbb R$ is the standard height function from $z$-plane. What I know that, $p,q,r,s$ are the only critical points having indices $0,1,1,2$ respectively, of $f$.  But, I can not understand the way of finding unstable manifolds. I can do this if I know how does the flow lines look like. Any help with intuitive or rigorous explanations will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: For intuition, try drawing your torus as a square with its sides identified and work out what everything should be. Better yet, google 'flow lines on torus' and check the images.

Comment: Try to count the "number of dimensions" of directions going to up and to down. Generally, it is given exactly by the Morse index. It is unstable when some directions goes to the top, and some goes to the bottom, meaning that a slight difference of direction from the base point will change where it goes